# Trigger on Junction object

Tags: junction-object

We are using standard case and solutions object which is used by the full license users.

However we have a custom case and  custom solution object, which is synchronized between the standard case and solution object using trigger on the standard case and solution..( custom case & solution object functionality was built for field tech's as we cannot afford the full license for every tech)

Challenge is synchronizing the standard case-solution junction object with custom case-solution junction object, as we cannot write a trigger on the junction object..(Is salesforce planning to introduce this functionality any time soon)

So we are planning to override the solution search page with vf page, in order to capture the select and delete of a solution on a case, should we override the "select" and " delete" links on the solution object..

Any other suggestions or solutions for this scenario...

Comment: how current does the synchronization have to be? One solution is scheduled apex that would look for all inserts/updates/deletions in the `CaseSolution` since its last successful run and then do the sync'ing

Comment: What do you mean by you can't write a trigger on the junction object. It's doable.